# Authenticating certain users Passport Strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am building a nodeJS backend for a ReactJS front end and would like to know the best way to handle authenticating **certain** users.

What I have so far is basically if a user is in my mongoDB collection, the authentication flow works as intended.

MongoDB Schema

```
OfficeSchema = new Schema({
  outlookID: String,
  displayName: String
});
```

I am using windows-live authentication (authenticates with outlook). The current implementation is shown below.

```
passport.use(
  new OutlookStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.OUTLOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: keys.OUTLOOK_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "/authorize-outlook"
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      const existingUser = await Office.findOne({ outlookID: profile.id });

      if (existingUser) {
        console.log("existing: ", existingUser);
        return done(null, existingUser);
      } else {
        console.log("no user found!");
        return done(null, false);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Finally, here are my routes:

```
app.get(
    "/auth/outlook",
    passport.authenticate("windowslive", {
      scope: [
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "offline_access",
        "https://outlook.office.com/Mail.Read"
      ]
    })
  );

  app.get(
    "/authorize-outlook",
    passport.authenticate("windowslive", { failureRedirect: "/login_failure" }),
    function(req, res) {
      // Successful authentication, redirect home.
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  );
```

Here are my questions:

1. Currently I do not know the best way to use done() function in my strategy, any tips would be great.
2. How do I pass an error message in my auth flow for unauthorized users (not in db), a static message is fine ("you are not authorized")
3. What is the best way to add users to this database (as I currently store their outlookID for the user)

Answering any of my questions would help greatly.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

For saving your new users you can simply save the new user and return the new object:

```
 Office.findOne({
          outlookId: profile.id
        }).then(existingUser => {
          if (existingUser) {
           //hand over the existing object no need to create
            done(null, existingUser);
          } else {
            //assuming that you want to save the new user and grant access
            new Office({ outlookId: profile.id }).save().then(newUser => {
             //hand over the new user object back to the passport session
            //same arguments, new user object
              done(null, newUser);
            });
          }
        });
```

//assuming you don't want to save the user `else {done(error, null}`

regarding the done object its possible to add error and info object responses to this in your strategy object.

```
done ("error string","user obj","info string")
```

That doesn't look pretty though so you may want to use a custom callback as described in the official [documents](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/#custom-callback):

You can then have your backend return the error object to your front end and handle it appropriately.

Comment: This should be in the comment section.

Comment: sorry clicked the wrong place.  updated with answer -  thanks for pointing out